# Change background of a buttons that was created dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net

I created some buttons, when the user click the button it does change the background color, but I need to change the background color to the default color when the user press another button

```
        max = Service.Max_id();
        max = max - 1;

        for (int i = 0; i < max; i++)
        {
            int x = i + 1;
            string num = (i + 1).ToString();

            DataTable dt = Service.fillWid((i + 1).ToString());
            string titlee = "";
            titlee = dt.Rows[0]["name"].ToString();

            ckplaceat = new Button();

            ckplaceat.ID = titlee;
            ckplaceat.Text = titlee;

            ckplaceat.Click += new EventHandler(ButtonClickOneEvent);


            ckplaceat.Style["Width"] = "115px";
            // ckplaceat.BackColor = Color.LightGray;
            ckplaceat.CssClass = "wButton";

            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(ckplaceat);
            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(" "));


            //PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br/>"));

        }
```

---

```
protected void ButtonClickOneEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            ckplaceat.BackColor = default(Color);
            btn = (Button)sender;

            btnclicked = (sender as Button).ID;

            for (int i = 0; i < max; i++)
            {
                idFunction();
              // changecolor();
                widgetChangeFun();
                btn.BackColor = Color.Black;
            }
```

Comment: Is btn getting populated as a button? I'd probably just do the color change via javascript in the HTML, you may be getting into something weird with the page lifecyle and it getting over written on the page load, or something like that.

Comment: You can iterate all the button inside PlaceHolder1.Controls having css CssClass = "wButton". Reset backColor of all button, then set color of clicked button. Better way is to change color using jquery/javascript and send an ajax request for button click. This will reduce one page load round trip.

Comment: You should create two classes, `active` and `default`, create a method in jquery which will remove classes from all those buttons and add the `active` class to the button which is pressed, call this jquery function from codebehind, that's it.